# Can't get simple .htaccess redirect to work

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I feel like this is a straightforward redirect but it doesn't seem to be working

I'm trying to take a url like `https://example.com/events/someeventid` and permanently 301 redirect it to `https://newexample.com/someeventid`

Here is what I have right now and I've tried several combinations of this to no avail

`RewriteRule ^events/(.*)$ https://newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]`

Comment: So what does "does not work" actually mean? Do you get an error? Does your service crash? Nothing happens? Does the universe implode?

Comment: Nothing happens

Comment: So you need to check: 1. is the interpretation of dynamic configuration files (".htaccess" style files) enabled at all for that host or that location? Hint: `AllowOberride` 2. did you switch on the rewriting engine before the rewriting rule? Hint: `RewriteEngine on` 3. where is that file located where you implemented that rule? what does your http server's error log file reveal?